# How to user can get updated version of notification of app for third party apps in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have seen few third party apps in iOS which are installed in iPhone/iPad, If those apps are updated version in app store, 
If we open the the app in device, We used to get notification like "New version updated in appstore, Please update."

Is this notification comes defaultly, Or do we need to customise something in iTunes connect or in our application?

I'm looking for how to come to know the installed version is lower than appstore version and if so, How to show popup and once user click on the some button in popup, should navigate to appstore for update the app.

Can anyone give suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality doesn't come by default.  If you want to build in-app dialogs or views, you could look at something like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to store the minimum or recommended app versions and some appropriate messaging.  You could also pass version information to your server and use push notifications to do something similar perhaps later when the user didn't have the app open.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the default behaviour. You should implement it by your self or can use some code https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren